# Ebay JSON API with VBA?

Tags: json, vba, ebay-api

I'm looking for a basic code example for making an EBAY API call in VBA using JSON?

I'm already using VBA to make calls to Ebay's older API ...but struggling to get off the ground with the new JSON API....I can't find any examples using VBA

Comment: There are examples here of posting JSON to API endpoints:  https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+json+api+post+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk00udJy7R9tJMoy6BGEgHOxFOGw-dQ:1589654615085&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji2pb1hLnpAhUDs54KHdpYB7EQrQIoBDAAegQIBBAN&biw=1536&bih=722

Comment: I'd seen that prior & leveraged on it a lot, but I can't get the header right. I'm trying to do a test search API call [link])https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/make-a-call.html) , Ebay say the header structure should have this... **Authorization = Bearer <Your-Application-token-value>** but I'm getting an error... **Token type in the Authorization header is invalid**